# Invalid sqlite datatypes

Tags: sqlite, types

I made a typo while creating a table, the data type for name should be TEXT:
   CREATE TABLE mytab (name EXT, num INT);

No errors were detected and inserts and selections were made OK:
   INSERT INTO mytab (name,num) VALUES ("Kim",42);
   SELECT * FROM mytab;

By specifying an invalid data type, does this default to a BLOB no data type specified?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't really have any invalid data types. It doesn't really have data *types* at all, at least not in the conventional sense of the term *data type*.

I think "[Determination of column affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)" is the part of SQLite documentation that answers your question. Your column of "type" EXT is  NUMERIC. Here are the rules.

1. If the declared type contains the string "INT" then it is assigned
   INTEGER affinity.
2. If the declared type of the column contains any of the strings "CHAR", "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has TEXT affinity. Notice that the type VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and is thus assigned TEXT affinity.
3. If the declared type for a column contains the string "BLOB" or if no type is specified then the column has affinity BLOB.
4. If the declared type for a column contains any of the strings "REAL", "FLOA", or "DOUB" then the column has REAL affinity.
5. Otherwise, the affinity is NUMERIC.

That page also defines *affinity*.

> The type affinity of a column is the recommended type for data stored
>   in that column. The important idea here is that the type is
>   recommended, not required. **Any column can still store any type of
>   data.** It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer to
>   use one storage class over another. The preferred storage class for a
>   column is called its "affinity". [Emphasis added]

Comment: Thank you.  I shall create a new table and copy the contents. I know its not strictly needed but it will tidy things up and make life easier for some future maintainer.